# Firefox won't play my .swf file

Tags: html, flash

I'm trying to get my flash animation working in Firefox. It works excellently in both Chrome and Internet Explorer, but when I open up the webpage in FF it doesn't load. What's the problem? I'm seriously stumped. I also checked to see if there was any issues with my browser playing Flash in general but it works.

Here's the link to the site: http://mason.gmu.edu/~klee49/dees_peanuts/about_us.html

And here's the code:

```
 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="FlashID" title="Dee's Peanuts Company Animation">
    <param name="movie" value="assets/deespeanutsanimation.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="10" />
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="assets/deespeanutsanimation.swf" width="800" height="600">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="10" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="800" height="600" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Hi, to whoever happens to have this problem in the future, I managed a workaround by using an iframe tag instead of object.

```
  <iframe src="assets/deespeanutsanimation.swf" width="640" height="480" title="Dee's Peanuts Company" border="0" /></iframe>
```

Comment: if firefox drop support for flash, then you cant

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?